# ActivityInstrumentation not showing up as option for superclass

Tags: android, junit, instrumentation

I am trying to write my first unit test for android, following a tutorial on youtube.  I need to add ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 as a superclass and it is not showing up as an option.  I searched the intertubes and found that I need to add it to my android manifest, however it is not listed as an option under instrumenation.  How do I hard code ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 in the manifest?